unknown file type '.pxd' when installing my package
I'm trying to install a package that I'm maintaining (pygtftk). I'm using the latest version and would like to go on with the development but I'm not able to install it under Python 3.10.14 due to some error with a pxd file (I'm clearly not expert in cython but I will work on it...).  When running:
 git clone git@github.com:dputhier/pygtftk.git
 cd pygtftk
 python setup.py install --user

It complains about "unknown file type '.pxd'".
 building 'pygtftk.stats.multiprocessing.multiproc' extension
 error: unknown file type '.pxd' (from 'pygtftk/stats/multiprocessing/multiproc.pxd')

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.
Best

pxd files — Cython 3.1.0a0 documentation

maybe it needs Cython to run. Did you install Cython?

Hi @furas. Yes !!

Here is the solution, I had to delete "pxd" files from 'sources' list in setup.py:
    cython_ologram_4 = Extension(name='pygtftk.stats.multiprocessing.multiproc',
                                 sources=["pygtftk/stats/multiprocessing/multiproc.pxd",
                                          "pygtftk/stats/multiprocessing/multiproc_structs.pxd",
                                          "pygtftk/stats/multiprocessing/multiproc.pyx"],
                                 extra_compile_args=extra_comp_cython,
                                 extra_link_args=extra_link_cython,
                                 language='c')

to
    cython_ologram_4 = Extension(name='pygtftk.stats.multiprocessing.multiproc',
                                 sources=["pygtftk/stats/multiprocessing/multiproc.pyx"],
                                 extra_compile_args=extra_comp_cython,
                                 extra_link_args=extra_link_cython,
                                 language='c') 

